# How can I apply border-radius on the image inside the card?

Tags: html, css

When I give the border-radius to a card, it doesn't get applied to the upper corners where the image is.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you give us some code so we can see what you have so far please?

Answer (score -1):

Add the border-radius to the img itself. Or add overflow:hidden to the div.